# Tokenizing/processing common grocery list input in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tokenize

I'm trying to write a small function in Swift that can accept common strings someone would use to add items to a grocery/shopping list and process them to extract the key data.

Sentences like the following, and their expected key data:

- "5 pounds of apples" – apples | pounds | 5
- "2 cans of tuna" – tuna | can | 2
- "Cantaloupes" – cantaloupes
- "A box of raisins" – raisins | box | 1
- "Handful of oats" – oats | handful

I haven't gotten around to recognizing spelled-out numbers ("*Four* boxes") or sizing words ("4 *large* boxes") yet, but that's besides the point right now. The issue I'm having is removing the split up components from the array when they've been recognized. For example, in the string "5 pounds of apples" after "of" is removed and "apples" is up next I get an `Array index out of range`.

Here's the full function - I've commented it a bit:

```
// Desired return dictionary: 'original', 'quantity', 'unit', 'item'

func extractGroceryTextData(string: String) -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject>? {
    var data: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

    // Split the string by spaces
    var components = string.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    // Add the original string to the dictionary
    data["original"] = string

    // Array of words that can be used as measurable units
    let groceryUnits: Array<String> = [
        "loaf",       "loaves",
        "box",        "boxes",
        "pack",       "packs",      "packages",
        "can",        "cans",
        "container",  "containers",
        "bunch",      "bunches",
        "handful",    "handfuls",
        "cup",        "cups",
        "tablespoon", "tablespoons",
        "teaspoon",   "teaspoons",
        "bottle",     "bottles"
    ]

    // Array of words that we don't need
    let groceryTossWords: Array<String> = [
        " ", "of", "lot"
    ]

    // Iterate through each word and tokenize when possible
    for (index, component) in enumerate(components) {
        var string = component.lowercaseString

        // First word is 'a', second word is not 'lot': 1 quantity
        if index == 0 && string == "a" && components[1].lowercaseString != "lot" {
            data["quantity"] = 1
            components.removeAtIndex(index)
        // 'a lot' is the beginning of the string: remove
        } else if string == "a" && components[index + 1] == "lot" {
            components.removeAtIndex(index)
            components.removeAtIndex(index + 1)
        // Component is found in groceryTossWords array: remove
        } else if contains(groceryTossWords, string) {
            components.removeAtIndex(index)
        // Component is found in groceryUnits array: unit
        } else if contains(groceryUnits, string) {
            data["unit"] = string
            components.removeAtIndex(index)
        // Component is a number (has a range within decimalDigitCharacterSet): quantity
        } else if string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet(), options: nil, range: nil) != nil {
            data["quantity"] = string
            components.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }

    // Leftover components joined together: item
    data["item"] = " ".join(components)

    return data
}
```

Please bare in mind that I'm relatively new to Swift. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Better yet - is there a better way of approaching this?

Comment: It looks like you’re changing `components` as you’re iterating over it. I don’t know whether this is legal in Swift—obviously it compiles, at least—but it makes the code harder to reason about. It’s not too surprising that you’d get a range error at some point.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Any idea how to otherwise approach it? Would I create an array of indexes during the for-loop and change `components` after it's finished?

Comment: Another thing that jumps out to me is that you’re accessing `components[1]` and `components[index+1]` without first checking that such elements exist. (In other words, `components[0]` or `components[index]` might be the last element of the array.)

Comment: Right now you’re looking for “interesting” pieces and calling `components.removeAtIndex(index)` on all of the *other* pieces. I would instead start with an empty list of interesting pieces and add components to that whenever you run across one.

Comment: @bdesham hey! I took your advice and instead of removing from the original components array I added the "interesting" elements to the already existing array of elements that I will be removing from components - in your opinion does this look a little better? http://swiftstub.com/318388054/

Comment: This still seems backward to me, but if you have further questions you should open a new question instead of us discussing it here.